# Верстка формы заказа (без JS) - HTML, CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Как правильно сверстать часть формы заказа? Есть 4 размера одежды и кнопка "заказать".
Если я правильно понимаю, то кнопку "заказать" мне нужно сверстать как `<input type="submit">`, как тогда быть с "кнопками-размерами"? Их верстать просто как ссылки или тоже через инпуты?!

Тут пример кода [cssdeck.com](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/gw7iq4tr)

```css
.shopnow, .sizeguide {
    width: 170px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
 
.size-btn, .shop-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border:1px solid #333333;
    font: 16px/50px "OpenSansBold";
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 170px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
 
.size-btn {
    width: 70px;  
    margin-right: 21px;
}
 
.size-btn:nth-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
 
input[value^=Shop] {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #777777;
}
 
.size-btn:hover, .shop-btn:hover {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopnow">
                <span class="size-btn">M</span>
                <span class="size-btn">L</span>
                <span class="size-btn">Xl</span>
                <span class="size-btn">XXL</span>
  <input class="shop-btn" type="submit" value="Shop now">
</div>
```

Второй вопрос, как выделить к примеру сразу 2 размера (если нужно будет 2 единицы товара заказать разных размеров). При выделении элементу с размером нужно добавить класс .active и его стилизовать. Или это можно сделать только с использованием JS?

Моя задача только верстка, но дальше программист будет кодить на PHP, если я сделаю кнопки размеров просто ссылками, то эти данные не будут отправляться на сервер, как данные формы.

Comment: как вариант https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/oud8azox/

Comment: в точку) именно то, что нужно было и без всяких скриптов) Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `input[type="checkbox"]` или `input[type="radio"]`

```css
shopnow,
.sizeguide {
  width: 170px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.shop-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  font: 16px/50px"OpenSansBold";
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
input[value^=Shop] {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #777777;
}
.size-btn:hover,
.shop-btn:hover {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[id^=size-] {
  display: none;
}
[id^=size-] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  font: 16px/50px"OpenSansBold";
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-right: 21px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[id^=size-] + label:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
[id^=size-]:checked + label {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopnow left">

  <input type="checkbox" id="size-m" value="M" name="size-1" />
  <label for="size-m">M</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="size-l" value="L" name="size-2" />
  <label for="size-l">L</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="size-xl" value="XL" name="size-3" />
  <label for="size-xl">XL</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="size-xxl" value="XXL" name="size-4" />
  <label for="size-xxl">XXL</label>

  <input class="shop-btn" type="submit" value="Shop now">
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/oud8azox/)